# PowerBI & Azure Client App Permissions to other applications

Tags: azure, powerbi

Attempting to do the https://github.com/PowerBI/getting-started-for-dotnet tutoriel, i am being blocked when we have to give permissions to other applications to an Client App : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn877542.aspx

I can't add PowerBI app on Azure :-(
The PowerBI name in the list of permissions to other applications can't be selected

Do you know why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually the issue is that you do not have a registered power bi user in your tenant.  You can create a user and sign them up at www.powerbi.com.  Once completed registering the user, you should be able to enable the application with power bi permissions.

Detailed instructions are here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn877542.aspx

Appreciate your using Power BI.

Lukasz P.

Power BI Team, Microsoft

If you'd like to stay up to date with the Power BI developer story updates you can register (http://solutions.powerbi.com/appsuggestion.html) or follow our blog (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem and my analysis says, you are using your work mail id when are you registering for Power BI (and work directory) and when you log into your Azure portal you are using your work mail id but you are on the microsoft directory rather then your work place directory hence you wont be able to see Power BI application listed in the options. One option is to migrate your Azure account to work directory.

HTH